# GET Request getting dupliacted in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, get-request

I have an web api which has a DownloadController. This controller calls another factory method and this factory method invokes an EXE and waits for this EXE to finish its execution.

I have hosted this on windows server 2012 R2 which has IIS 8.5.
I am making a GET request to this web api controller as below:

http://myapplication.myserver.com/api/download?contenttype=xxxxxxxxxx

```
web Api:

    // GET api/download
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
             ...............
             CreateAndGetZipFile();
        }

Factory Method:

        public void CreateAndGetZipFile()
        {
           ...............
           ZipFileCreatorExe.Start();
           ZipFileCreatorExe.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Now when I make the GET request to download the ZIP file in VS it is working as excpected and downloading the ZIP file. But when hosted on IIS 8.5 on WinServer2012r2.

IIS is creating Multiple GET requests and launching **ZipFileCreatorExe** multiple times and after the ZIP file is returned the multiple instances of EXEs launched by IIS are not exiting sometimes which has actually making the application useless.

I have checked the IIS logs and it clearly shows the mutliple GET requests being made. one more thing to add is that, every GET request is made after 20 or 30 seconds.

Please help.

Comment: If your IIS is handling multiple requests (and you see this in logs), then maybe the problem is with request sending? So, how are you calling your web-api? I think, IIS receives real multiple external requests. For example, If two clients will call this method of your API it will result in two separate threads on IIS, and finally in two launched .EXE. If you want to avoid this situation, you should modify your factory, to run only one .EXE at moment.

Comment: I am pretty sure that only one request is made. The request is made through the url send in mail which is a direct  GET request for tthe ZIP files.